# Unable to add marker, for such LatLngs

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the following code to add markers on a Google Map, using Google-Maps-Android-V2

```
ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);

marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(ll)
                    .title("Title")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

The problem is, markers are not added for values like

> (18.5087013, 73.8125)

For values like

> (18.59672737121582,73.76543426513672)

The marker is added.

Any rules(precision) for the values of lat and lng to construct a `LatLng`??

Comment: is this javascript code?  You mention Google Maps for Android yet the code seems to apply to the javascript API

Comment: Yeah same. But its android

Comment: oh nice, didn't realize they added that feature to the android version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this change in your position:- `ll = new LatLng(lat*1e6, lng*1e6);`

Comment: This didn't work. Even if it does work, I have a problem: **If i apply this for a working case, it stops working.** And i don't know when to apply or not.